# Android MVP - Presenter displaying values (best practices)

Tags: android, design-patterns, mvp

I started to learn *MVP* but I have a few questions related the *Presenter*. For example, if I have a really simple *Activity* that only displays a few information that I got from another *Activity*. At the moment I am just displaying the value without sending it to the *Presenter*.

Should I send the values to the *Presenter* so that the *Presenter* will call the methods in my *Activity* to display? Or can I just "ignore" the *Presenter*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I send the values to the presenter and the presenter will call the methods in my activity to display?

You should.

> Or can I just "ignore" the presenter?

You better should not.

One of the benefits of structuring your code using the *MVP* pattern is the ability to unit test the structural units. Any *Presenter* should be framework- (in *Android*, meaning view- ) independent which makes it possible to unit test it. So, if you "ignore" the *Presenter* you won't be able to unit test the *Activity* methods invocations.

For commercial app development unit testing is a relevant part.